# Different scanner data types in one loop. What to be done?

Tags: java

The background: this is the final loop from a simple program in which the user first inputs any number of integer (double) command-line arguments, then I put them in an array of length [args.length], and then I allow the user to enter any integer and check whether it is in the array. I want the loop to end and the program to terminate only when the user enters the string "exit".

But I don't know how to do this. Surely, it can't be too hard to solve this. (P.S. I made a static scanner method at the beginning so it's not like my problem is that the computer's like 'you can't call on the same Mr. stdin twice, idiot!').

```
while (true) {
    double userstdin = stdin.nextDouble();
    String exit = stdin.nextLine();
    if (contains(arguments, userstdin) == true) {
      System.out.println("This number is in your array.");
    }
    else if (contains(arguments, userstdin) == false) {
      System.out.println("This number is not in your array.");
    }
    if (exit.equals("exit")) {
      System.out.println("Terminating.");
      return;
    }
}
```

I need the user to be able to enter either a number, or the word "exit". How can I do this in my loop?

Comment: So what you want is the user to be able to enter either a number or the word "exit"?

Comment: yes, that is all i want to do

Comment: I have a feeling a wroth is like a small badger with rather sharp teeth. Will that feel your wrath too?

Comment: Why do you need `else if`? It either contains or not... Also `== true` is redundant

Comment: @halfer [wroth](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wroth) is a word... pretty much interchangeable with wrath though.

Comment: Yep, I looked it up @Roddy, but I liked my definition better!

Comment: Thanks lads! So speedy.

Comment: On windows you are very likely to have a problem with stdin.nextLine() if you are using System.in for stdin.

Windows only sends input to java when it gets a full buffer or an end of input (ctrl-d I think), not each time you hit return.

Comment: Oops, I am sure your @Noam alter-ego would not make the assumption that everyone is a "lad" here. Some non-male members of the community have said in the past they find that exclusionary. Let's be as welcoming here as we can please!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a user to be able to enter multiple types of data in a single input, grab it as a String and then parse it to determine the datatypes you actually got.

Let's assume that your scenario is that a user can enter a number or the word "exit". Any other input is invalid.

First, capture whatever the user gives you -- string, number, whatever:

```
String input = stdin.nextLine();
```

Then try to parse it into your use cases:

```
if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    // user entered exit
    System.exit(0);
}

// Check to see if it's a number. There's a number of ways to do this, but for simplicity's
// sake, we'll just try to parse it.
try {
    Double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
    // do something here with number;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // it was not a double, whatever it was.
    // put some error handling here, maybe a message about a bad/unrecognized input
}
```

Note that checking data types like this is considered bad practice (eg. trying to parse then catching an Exception if you fail.) I'm just doing it here as an illustration of the technique.

Comment: Roddy, you are my hero

Answer (score 1):

How about you read once, and parse later?

```
while (true) {
    String userstdin = stdin.nextLine();
    if (userstdin.equals("exit")) {
      System.out.println("Terminating.");
      return;
    }

    double d = Double.parseDouble(userstdin);
    if (contains(arguments, d)) {
      System.out.println("This number is in your array.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("This number is not in your array.");
    }
}
```

Or, more succinctly

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(userstdin);
String in = contains(arguments, d) ? "is" : "is not";
System.out.printf("This number %s in your array.\n", in);
```

Note: `try-catching` the `Double.parseDouble` is a good idea

Comment: you are also my hero

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you could first check if the user provided string is equalIgnoreCase() to "exit".

If not you call Integer.parseInt() on that string. If that call does not throw an exception, the input was in fact a number.